# Firebase firestore data inconsistency

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a project which consists of a **"following"** and **"unfollowing"** feature just like a social media app.
Each time a user follows or unfollows four different actions are run for both the functionality.
Let's say, for the **following feature**, I have the below code,

```
export const followUser = async (profile)=>{
  try{
     await db.collection('_').doc('_').set({...});       //line 1
     await db.collection('_').doc('_').set({...});       //line 2
     await db.collection('_').doc('_').update({...});    //line 3
     await db.collection('_').doc('_').update({...});    //line 4
  }
  catch(error){
     throw error;
  }
}
```

I found out that there could be **data inconsistency** as for some reason if **line3** fails it will go into the catch block but **line1** and **line2** have already been executed causing inconsistency.
**Is there a way in which if any of the four actions fails I can move to catch block without any single action been executed.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need in this case are firestore [batch writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) which ensure atomicity across writes, so either all your writes fail or all of them are successful leaving no data inconsistencies behind.

So you can do something like:

```
const batch = db.batch();

batch.set(ref, {...});
batch.set(ref, {...});
batch.update(ref, {...});
batch.update(ref, {...});

await batch.commit();
```

Please note that a single batch can contain up to 500 write operations (set, update and deletes operations).